# Quoting with ssh command with a function call

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I need to execute the shell command as follows:

```
ssh <device> "command"
```

command is invoked as:

```
$(typeset); <function_name> \"arguement_string\"; cd ...; ls ...
```

How exactly to quote here? Is this correct?

```
""$(typeset); <function_name> \"arguement_string\""; cd ...; ls ..."
```

I am confused with this quoting in shell scripts.

Comment: Don't double your quotes. Just escape any inside the inner string.

Comment: Describe what you're trying to do more precisely, please. Programmatically generating ssh commands (if such is what you're attempting) is tricky; we need to know the details if we're going to get them right. (If you're just trying to pass along a constant script, then the existing answer by @hek2mgl has it right).

Comment: quite related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205567/231113

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to do the quoting by hand -- ask the shell to do it for you!

```
command_array=( function_name "first argument" "second argument" )
printf -v command_str '%q ' "${command_array[@]}"
ssh_str="$(typeset); $command_str"
ssh machine "$ssh_str"
```

You can then build up `command_array` as you wish -- using logic to conditionally append values, with only the kind of quoting you'd usually refer to use to those values, and let `printf %q` add all additional quoting needed to make the content safe to pass through ssh.

---

If you're trying to incrementally build up a script, you can do that like so:

```
remote_script="$(typeset)"$'\n'
safe_append_command() {
  local command_str
  printf -v command_str '%q ' "$@"
  remote_script+="$command_str"$'\n'
}

safe_append_command cp "$file" "$destination"
safe_append_command tar -cf /tmp/foo.tar "${destination%/*}"
# ...etc...

ssh machine "$remote_script"
```

Note that in this case, all expansions take place **locally**, when the script is being generated, and shell constructs such as redirection operators cannot be used (except by embedding them in a function you then pass to the remote system with `typeset`). Doing so means that no data passed to `safe_append_command` can be treated as code -- foreclosing large classes of potential security holes at the cost of flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
ssh machine <<'EOF'
hello() {
    echo "hello $1!"
}

hello "world"
EOF
```

Note that I wrapped the starting `EOF` in single quotes. Doing so prevents bash from interpreting variables or command substitutions in the local shell.

Comment: Definitely the right thing if the remote script is intended to be constant. I'm not sure the question makes it clear whether this is the case.