# How do you export local shell variables into a multi-command ssh?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to `ssh` to another server in a shell script and run some scripts.

Currently my line looks something like:

```
ssh user@$SERVER '$(typeset -a >> /dev/null); PROFILE_LOCATION=`locate db2profile| grep -i $INST_NAME| grep -v bak`; . $PROFILE_LOCATION; function1; function2;'
```

I've tried both `'` and `"` , as well as using a combination of those with `\;` or `';'`

How do I use the variables I have in my current shell script in my `ssh` into another server and running multiple commands? Thanks!!

Comment: This is already asked and answered -- might be worth looking through the existing knowledgebase.

Comment: ...that said, I disagree with whoever marked this migrate-to-SuperUser -- being able to run functions on a remote server is very much a scripting-focused concern.

Comment: BTW, consider making a habit of using lower-case shell variable names; see the POSIX conventions for environment variable names in the fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html (specifying that upper-case names are used by the operating system and shell, and that applications are guaranteed to be able to use lowercase names without conflicting). Environment variables and shell variables share a namespace (setting a shell variable with a name that overlaps an environment variable will overwrite it), so these conventions apply to those too.

Comment: re: potential duplicates, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729374/executing-a-local-shell-function-on-a-remote-host-over-ssh-using-python, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083980/quoting-with-ssh-command-with-a-function-call

Answer (score 1):

If you want function declarations, and your shell is bash, use `typeset -p` rather than `typeset -a` (which will provide a textual dump of variables but not functions). Also, you need to actually run that in a context where it'll be locally evaluated (and ensure that your remote shell is something that understands it, not `/bin/sh`).

The following hits all those points:

```
evaluate_db2profile() {
  local db2profile
  db2profile=$(locate db2profile | grep -i "$INST_NAME" | grep -v bak | head -n 1)
  [ -n "$db2profile" ] && . "$db2profile"
}

ssh "user@$SERVER" bash -s <<EOF
$(typeset -p)
evaluate_db2profile
function1
function2
EOF
```

- Because `<<EOF` is used rather than `<<'EOF'`, the `typeset -p` command is run locally and substituted into the heredoc. (You could also accomplish this by using double rather than single quotes in the one-line formulation, but see below).
- Defining `evaluate_db2profile` locally as a function ensures that `typeset -p` will emit it in a format that the remote shell can evaluate, without need to be concerned about escaping.
- Using `bash -s` on the remote command line ensures that the shell interpreting your functions is bash, not `/bin/sh`. If your code is written for ksh, run `ksh -s` to achieve that same effect.